# Franck-Hertz experiment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy

In the [Franck-Hertz experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franck%E2%80%93Hertz_experiment) why are the peaks much sharper than the troughs?

Also our data analysis suggested that the distance between the peaks is smaller (nearer to $4.9 \ $ eV ) than the distance between the troughs ($5.1 \ $ eV ). Is there a reason behind this?